# How to tell if it's British Summer Time

Tags: c#, .net, dst, datetimeoffset

I have the following code, which *should* return an offset of 60 (to show that in the UK at present, we are in British Summer Time - ie. 60 minutes ahead of GMT):

```
var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Greenwich Standard Time");
DateTimeOffset localServerTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
double off = localServerTime.Offset.TotalMinutes;
return off;
```

However, it returns 0.

Could anyone please help fix this for me?

Comment: You didn't use `info` anywhere. So your `off` will be current time zone offset.

Comment: @vc74 The question is misleading. The `info` variable is initialised but otherwise unused. The returned offset is based only on `DateTimeOffset.Now`.

Comment: Interesting. That works fine for me (czech daylight savings time). Are you sure your server is setup correctly, with the proper time zone?

Comment: @vc74 UTC == GMT, always. You seem to be saying that Britain is currently in GMT (or UTC) rather than BST, but I don't believe that's correct, and Wikipedia agrees with me that BST doesn't end until next weekend.

Comment: BST doesn't end until sunday and `DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset.TotalMinutes` returns 60 for me in the UK right now.

Comment: @hvd You're right, so the server must be configured in GMT in this case

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime Method (DateTimeOffset)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382013(v=vs.100).aspx) to find if it is currently Daylight saving for your Timezone.

```
var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Greenwich Standard Time");
DateTimeOffset localServerTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
bool isDaylightSaving = info.IsDaylightSavingTime(localServerTime);
```

There are further examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Using the timezone "Greenwich Standard Time" didn't work for me as it apparently doesn't support daylight savings. I had to use "GMT Standard Time" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your machine is not configured correctly if you get 0 and live in the UK.  Probable causes are:

- The machine's time zone is not set correctly.  Click the clock on the taskbar to correct.
- The machine is not configured to observe daylight savings.  Click the clock.
- The database that TimeZoneInfo consults for daylight savings rules in out of date or corrupted.  It is stored in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones registry key.

Be careful about making radical changes, having it configured wrong might well have been done intentionally to work around some kind of flaw in a business-critical app that runs on the server.  Talk to whomever administers the server first.

Answer (score 0):

To master conversion from one timezone to anther you need to see what's supported (how?) and what's not.

```
foreach (var tz in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
{
    Console.WriteLine("TimeZone Offset: {0} Name : {1}, Supports DLS: {2}", tz.BaseUtcOffset,tz.StandardName,tz.SupportsDaylightSavingTime);
}
```

This should give you the list all timezones including info about DayLightSaving.
Notice that:

TimeZone Offset: 00:00:00 Name : Greenwich Standard Time, Supports DLS: False

TimeZone Offset: 00:00:00 Name : GMT Standard Time, Supports DLS: True

So you need to use "GMT Standard Time" because it supports daylight saving already. No work needs to be done.

Here is sample code:

```
private static string GetBSTTimeStamp(string timestamp)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(timestamp);
    //TimeZoneInfo bst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
    //Console.WriteLine("Time zone supports dls? {0}", bst.SupportsDaylightSavingTime);
    //Console.WriteLine("Time zone offset? {0}", bst.BaseUtcOffset);
    DateTime dateTimeInUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(dt, "Eastern Standard Time", "GMT Standard Time");
    return dateTimeInUtc.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/).

The following code works with Noda Time 1.4 and higher:

```
var zone = NodaTime.TimeZones.TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ForId("Europe/London");
var zonedClock = NodaTime.SystemClock.Instance.InZone(zone);
var zonedDateTime = zonedClock.GetCurrentZonedDateTime();
bool isDST = zonedDateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime();
Console.WriteLine(isDST);
```

- `zone` is a [`DateTimeZone`](https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/api/NodaTime.DateTimeZone.html) object representing the UK's timezone, "Europe/London"
- `zonedClock` is a [`ZonedClock`](https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/api/NodaTime.ZonedClock.html) object which represents, in this case, the system clock and the UK's timezone
- `zonedDateTime` is a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/api/NodaTime.ZonedDateTime.html) object representing the current date and time in the timezone ("the current instant provided by the underlying clock, adjusted to the time zone of this object")
- `isDST` is a boolean indicating whether the current instant is in DST or not. At the time of writing (April 2018) this evaluates to `true`

---

With earlier versions of Noda where `ZonedClock` is not available, we can do this instead:

```
var zone = NodaTime.TimeZones.TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ForId("Europe/London");
var now = Instant.FromDateTimeOffset(DateTimeOffset.Now);
var zonedDateTime = new ZonedDateTime(now, zone);
bool isDST = zonedDateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime();
```